# How to set and limit my resolution to 640x480

Tags: 12.04, xorg

How can I set and limit the resolution in Ubuntu 12 to 640x480
There's not much in the xorg.conf file anymore, so I'm guessing this is no longer the place to do it?

I can't do it using the GUI either because it doesn't show me the 640x480 option.

While setting the resolution the computer is connected to a normal screen
but later it will be connected to a screen that only supports 640x480 and doesn't report its supported modes to the computer.

The only thing in my xorg.conf (by default) is this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

**Update, in response to Kamil's answer:**

I do not have the gdm folder, but I get the idea
However if I execute those commands I get the following

```
xrandr --newmode "640x480_60.00"   23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
Serial number of failed request:  19
Current serial number in output stream:  19
root@timothy-desktop:~# xrandr --addmode default 640x480_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
root@timothy-desktop:~# xrandr --output default --mode 640x480
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Note that VGA1 is default in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your default resolution as 640x480

1. Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and issue:

   ```
   cvt 640 480
   ```
2. Copy the output
3. Open the configuration file:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/gdm/Init/Default
   ```
4. Search for :

   ```
   PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"  
   OLD_IFS=$IFS
   ```
5. Add the output you just copied in step 2, for example:

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "640x480_60.00"   23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 -hsync +vsync
   xrandr --addmode VGA1 640x480_60.00
   xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 640×480
   ```
6. Save and reboot.

Comment: I do not have a gdm folder in my /etc folder

Comment: Can't find this folder on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 3):

To set your resolution to 640x480. Open a terminal and write:

```
   xrandr -s 640x480
```

Comment: Tried this, nothing changes

Comment: works for me on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS